# Occurrences and Arrays positions

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Lets say I have this arrays:

```
likes = [4,6,42,72,7,4,42,56,6,24];
time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

And when clicking in one of the bar charts I have, I'm forwarded to the current time, according to the array `likes` position.

```
this.click(function () {
    var pos = result_likes.indexOf(this.bar.value);
    var pos2 = result_time[pos];

    setCurTime(pos2);
});
```

However when I have the same likes values, for instance number 4, there will be two positions of it, and the SetCurTime, will only forward me to the first time when "like=4 appears (`timecode[0];`)

How can I solve this and be forward to the right time position?

Comment: What's `this` and `this.bar`?

Comment: @Bergi According to gRaphael, I think it's the Raphael element, created by: `var r = Raphael("holder")`,

Comment: Can you bind the click handler for each element? Such as `this.click((function(pos){return function(){setCurTime(result_time[pos]};})(this.val));`

Comment: @NateBarr Where is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/K5kfc/2/ :)  
You can see how it works, and what's happening...

Comment: `var pos2 = result_time[this.bar.id];`

Comment: God bless you Nate Barr! :)
You just solved my problem. Many, many thanks! :D
I didn't know that each of those bars have an id...

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed meta data in the bar elements to solve this problem. For instance, you can use [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset) like such:

```
<div class="bar" data-index"5">4</div>
```

You would dynamically generate this of course, to create each bar with the proper index and value.

Then in your click handler would be:

```
this.click(function () {
    var pos = this.bar.dataset.index;
    var pos2 = result_time[pos];

    setCurTime(pos2);
});
```

Comment: The bars are created according to [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) script. I can't change the way how this is being created, so unfortunately I can't use your solution...

Answer (score 0):

In light of you using the gRaphael library, perhaps you could crawl the bar elements to see which element it is within the chart, like this:

```
this.click(function(evt) {
    var pos = 0; 
    var child = evt.currentTarget; 
    var type = child.nodeName;
    while( (child = child.previousSibling) != null && type === child.nodeName)
        pos++;

    var pos2 = result_time[pos];

    setCurTime(pos2);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, but I think this code doesn't work has expected... `pos2`is always equals to 1, independently on which bar I pressed!

Comment: Does it work for you now? I replaced `child = this` with `child = evt.currentTarget`

Comment: No. The same thing happens... I pressed a bar chart, and I'm forwarded always to time instant 1.

Comment: I'm not getting your point... How do you expect that something will be returned, if you are not retrieving any value from the bars (like likes values, x position, etc). I think that's why it always returning 1. Did you get my point?

Comment: What is the click handler parameter? Is it an evt obj? This looks at the DOM structure of the chart. If you render 10 bars, each will be a `<rect></rect>` element within the parent `<svg></svg>` element. This will start at the one that was clicked and crawl up the DOM tree counting how many other elements of the same type are present (if you click the fourth, it will find 3 more above - equivalent to the index of the clicked bar). Looking more into gRaphael, I don't think this is a robust solution as you might have more than one chart within the same svg and it apparently has a flat hierarchy.

Comment: That's a good question... I'm just starting to work with gRaphael, and I'm exploring it. But yes, this is a DOM structure of charts, and they are constituted by `<rect>`, but we are missing something...

Answer (score 0):

Reposting comment here for any others who need a simliar solution:

```
var pos2 = result_time[this.bar.id];
```